# error trying to use marshmallow_dataclass

Tags: python, marshmallow

I am trying to use marshmallow_dataclass in a python (3.9) test in pycharm to try it (marshmallow_dataclass) out and get an error.
Not sure what I am doing wrong. I have installed marshmallow_dataclass (8.1.0)
I have so far been successful in using marshmallow (3.8.0) and marshmallow_oneofschema (2.1.0) so far
(new to python but not programming)

Code is:

```
import marshmallow_dataclass
import unittest


class Tests(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_serialize(self):
        print("Hello")
```

Error is:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\_jb_unittest_runner.py", line 35, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(argv=args, module=None, testRunner=unittestpy.TeamcityTestRunner, buffer=not JB_DISABLE_BUFFERING))
  File "C:\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\unittest\main.py", line 100, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "C:\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\unittest\main.py", line 147, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "C:\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\unittest\main.py", line 158, in createTests
    self.test = self.testLoader.loadTestsFromNames(self.testNames,
  File "C:\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 220, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "C:\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 220, in <listcomp>
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "C:\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\xxxx\dev\repos\python\solar\pvoutput-publisher\test\test_serialization\test_delme.py", line 1, in <module>
    import marshmallow_dataclass
  File "C:\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\marshmallow_dataclass\__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    import typing_inspect
  File "C:\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\typing_inspect.py", line 25, in <module>
    from typing_extensions import Literal
  File "C:\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\typing_extensions.py", line 2084, in <module>
    def TypeAlias(self, parameters):
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'doc'```
````

Answer (score 0):

I hit similar error on python 3.9 alpha release (3.9.0a5), I am not sure the version of  `typing_extensions.py` in your environment (maybe it is [v3.7.4.3](https://github.com/python/typing/blob/3.7.4.3/typing_extensions/src_py3/typing_extensions.py#L2084) ?).

The root cause is that :

- the function `TypeAlias()` is decorated directly with the class `_TypeAliasForm`, which is subclass of `typing._SpecialForm` in python stardard library
- `typing._SpecialForm.__init__()` in your python environment has extra argument `doc` , since  the class `_TypeAliasForm` is a decorator for `TypeAlias()`, Python couldn't provide extra argument `doc` when instantiating `_TypeAliasForm` on decorating process.

In short, your `typing_extensions.py` is out of sync with your python interpreter, see the source code for detail:

- [`TypeAlias()` and `_TypeAliasForm` class](https://github.com/python/typing/blob/3.7.4.3/typing_extensions/src_py3/typing_extensions.py#L2084) .
- [`typing._SpecialForm.__init__()` in python 3.9.0a5](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.0a5/Lib/typing.py#L321)
- [`typing._SpecialForm.__init__()` in python 3.9.0a6](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.0a6/Lib/typing.py#L313)

It seems that the issue happens from python 3.9.0a1 to 3.9.0a5, so the solutions are :

- upgrade your python to final release version
- if you are not allowed to upgrade python for some other reasons, maybe you can monkey-patch `typing._SpecialForm` , here is the example for monkey-patching :

```py
from typing import _SpecialForm
origin_getitem = _SpecialForm.__getitem__
def patch_init(self, name, doc=None):
    if doc is None and callable(name):
        if hasattr(name, '__doc__'):
            doc = name.__doc__
    self._name = name
    self._doc = doc
def patch_getitem(self, parameters):
    item = None
    if callable(self._name):
        item = self._name(self=self, parameters=parameters)
    else:
        item = origin_getitem(self=self, parameters=parameters)
    return item

if not hasattr(_SpecialForm.__init__, 'patched'):
    _SpecialForm.__init__ = patch_init
    setattr(_SpecialForm.__init__, 'patched', True)
if not hasattr(_SpecialForm.__getitem__, 'patched'):
    _SpecialForm.__getitem__ = patch_getitem
    setattr(_SpecialForm.__getitem__, 'patched', True)
```